# Не подключается PostgreSQL из Docker к Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask

Есть вот такой контейнер Docker с PostgreSQL и pgadmin:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_db
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: questions
    hostname: pg_db
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: valerfilatoff@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
```

Он нужен для подключения API на Flask к базе данных, но при разных вариациях написания URI для SQLAlchemy, в ответ одна и та же ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\main.py", line 33, in index
    same_question = db.session.query(Question).filter_by(text=question['question']).first()
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2747, in first
    return self.limit(1)._iter().first()  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2846, in _iter
    result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2232, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2117, in _execute_internal
    conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1984, in _connection_for_bind
    return trans._connection_for_bind(engine, execution_options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in _connection_for_bind
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state_changes.py", line 137, in _go
    ret_value = fn(self, *arg, **kw)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1111, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3269, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 147, in __init__
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2431, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3293, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1268, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\bewise_interview\task1\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) 
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Вот так писались варианты URI:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://admin:root@localhost:5432/questions"
```

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "postgresql://admin:root@pg_db:5432/questions"
```

Но так ничего и не заработало. Перерыл тонны подобных ошибок, но там всё упиралось в неправильные пароли или перепутанные названия. Что с этим в итоге делать?

Comment: pgadmin коннектится к базе? И само приложение, которое коннектится к postgresql, тоже в докере?

Comment: само приложение не в docker, а pgadmin всё видит, вообще хорошо себя чувствует